# hightchart : centered value and arrow

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I would like to make graphics like this one with hightchart.js. So I would like to have the value on the outside of the graph, in front of the center of his area and a small triangle pointing on it. Do you know how to do that? Thank you for your help.
[image: Donut chart with arrows]

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to work on connectorPath, internal Highcharts function for changing connector path to the triangle:

```
var H = Highcharts,
    pick = H.pick;
H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.connectorPath = function(labelPos) {
    var angle = labelPos[7],
        x = labelPos.x,
        y = labelPos.y,
        M = 'M',
        L = 'L';
    return [
        M,
        x - Math.cos(angle) * 20, y - 20 * Math.sin(angle),
        L,
        labelPos[4] - Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 3) * 20, labelPos[5] - 20 * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 3),
        L,
        labelPos[4] - Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 3) * 20, labelPos[5] - 20 * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 3),
        L,
        x - Math.cos(angle) * 20, y - 20 * Math.sin(angle),
    ];
};
```

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L96f7d1a/1/

Comment: Very impressive. Thank you very much for that answer. Is there a way to move the values so that they find themselves right in front of the triangle points (or better anyway)? the offset is seen much on the high and low parts of the Pie Chart (See Safari on your jsfiddle). Ideally, the texts should be centered on the line formed by the top of the triangles and the center of the graph. Do you see a solution? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[an image to understand much more the position of the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Bq4.png)